# Vertical-ish autorows

Tags: tables

I have a large amount of data I am putting in a paper. It is a sequence of numbers where the index is even.

```
2  4    14 8
4  6    16 10
6  6    18 10
8  8    20 8
10 4    22 12
12 8    24 8
```

There can be over 300 entries like this. I am looking for a way to make a table where the data is listed as above (the index first moves down a row and then over a column) and so that the number of columns can be (somewhat) easily adjusted.

Does anyone have a recommendation for this?

Comment: are headings required on any of the columns?  if now, what i'd try is a `tabbing` environment, embedded in `multicols`.  then you'd mainly have to decide how many columns you want.  since `tabbing` breaks freely at the bottom of a page, it seems it should not have any problems getting "subdivided" into columns.

Comment: Given the large number of entries I'd use something like [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Headings are required. Regardless, I am not sure I see how to use the tabbing environment. It seems that one must set the 1st row, then 2nd row, etc. This means the entire table needs to be reset if the number of rows or columns is to be changed.

Comment: @Andrew: This is interesting, thanks for informing me of this. It would still involve some moving around, but it is much less work. However, I've decided just to write a *nix script to take in a data file and output the latex code using the table dimensions as parameters.